# rails activerecord validation with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have model associations as follows:

```
     class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :group_links, :dependent => :destroy
     end

      class GroupLink < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :group
       validates_presence_of :group_id
       validates_presence_of :url, :message => "We need a url to create a link"
       validates_uniqueness_of :url, :message => "A link with this url already exists"
       validates_presence_of :text, :message => "We need a text to create a link"
       validates_uniqueness_of :text, :message => "A link with this text already exists"
      end
```

I want it to work like in each group the group links should be unique. However the way it works is, it throws the validations errors even if some other group has thins group link.

what am i doing wrong?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I used :scope => :group_id for my uniqueness validations to get this to work